# How prove this indentity with $\sum_{0\le i\le l,0\le j\le m,0\le k\le n}\frac{f(a_{i},b_{j},c_{k})}{N(a_{i},b_{j},c_{k})}=1$

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

> Let
>   $$f(x,y,z)=x^ly^mz^n+\sum_{s=1}^{t}A_{s}x^{p_{s}}y^{q_{s}}z^{r_{s}}$$
>   where $l,m,n$ is postive integers,and  $A_{s}(1\le s\le t)$is real numbers,$p_{s},q_{s},r_{s}(1\le s\le t)$ is  non-negative integer numbers，and such
>   $$\min\{p_{s}-l,q_{s}-m,r_{s}-n\}<0,\forall 1\le s\le t$$
>   Give the three piece of real numbers $$a_{0}<a_{1}<\cdots<a_{l},
> b_{0}<b_{1}<\cdots<b_{m},c_{0}<c_{1}<\cdots<c_{n}$$

and Define 
$$N(a_{i},b_{j},c_{k})=\prod_{0\le i'\le l,i'\neq i}(a_{i}-a_{i'})\prod_{0\le j'\le m,
j'\neq j}(b_{j}-b_{j'})\prod_{0\le k'\le n,k'\neq k}(c_{k}-c_{k'})$$

> show that
>   $$\sum_{0\le i\le l,0\le j\le m,0\le k\le n}\dfrac{f(a_{i},b_{j},c_{k})}{N(a_{i},b_{j},c_{k})}=1$$

This problem is from (numerical calculation) book,the author hint use [interpolation polynomial in the Lagrange form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial),see $f(x,y,z)$ both  of the coefficient with $x^ly^mz^n$,

But I can't use it.

can you someone can explain detail? Thank you